# How to apply css to the inferior class in Vuejs

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

I have a html file that works by button in vuejs.
The v-bind:class can be used for one tag like below.
It dissapears depends on the boolean of bool data.

```
<h3 v-bind:class="{active: bool}">{{counter.document}}</h3>
```

But my goal is I want to appear and dissapear the inferior class depends on the superior class condition.
How can I make it correctly? Thank you so much for reading.

```
<div v-bind:class="{active: orderOptions.item.document}">
    <button v-on:click="counter.document -= 1">-</button>
    <h3>{{counter.document}}</h3>
    <button v-on:click="counter.document += 1">+</button>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use condition in `V-bind:style` VueJS:

```
v-bind:style= "[condition ? {styleA} : {styleB}]"


<div v-bind:style="[orderOptions.item.document ?"active",""]">
    <button v-on:click="counter.document -= 1">-</button>
    <h3>{{counter.document}}</h3>
    <button v-on:click="counter.document += 1">+</button>
 </div>
```